# Id link don't work in smartphones

Tags: html

I have a menu with an Id link like that:

```
<a href="http://mywebpage.com/pruducts/#id">
```

It works perfect in computers but if i try it in smartphones the link do not work.

I've tryed several ways, but it never works.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of it on mobile, showing that the link isn't working? Mobile browsers tend to tidy up the URL.

Comment: `com/pruducts/` should be `com/products/` ?

Comment: could you give the code for the entire page? I would like to test it out